# "Order by price" returns a weird order in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a local-only project which I'm working on where I have a table with `id`, `title` and `price` fields.

Example info:

```
ID || Title || Price
1 - Title 1 - 8.00
2 - Title 2 - 75.00
3 - Title 3 - 70.00
```

When I try to `ORDER BY price` it comes back like this:

```
8.00
75.00
70.00
```

Statement:

```
$query = mysql_query("Select * From table ORDER BY price DESC");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the real data and code used to view it? I suspect that is the problem, not the query.

Comment: What's the datatype for column `Price`? If possible please post the output of `SHOW COLUMNS FROM <the table in question>;`

Comment: my guess is that the column `price` (in the MySQL database) is a `varchar` or `text`. Try changing it to `int` or something.

Comment: p is lowercase, it should be capitalized. Is it correct in your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `price` column must have a character `CHAR() or VARCHAR()` type rather than a numeric type. Cast it as a `DECIMAL` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
Select * From table ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC
```

The real fix for this would be to change the `price` data type to a proper numeric type.