# MySQL, price ordering

Tags: php, mysql

In a MySQL database, prices are stored in a way like this:

- 20.000
- 25.000
- 25.000
- 10.000
- 120

where the dot stands for thousand (italian currency, like comma in US).
If I try to sort these data with "Order by price ASC" I have the following order:

- 10.000
- 20.000
- 25.000
- 120

It seems that it confuses the dot with the comma.
Infact, 120 is the last but it should be the first. Is there a way to order the sequence correctly?

Comment: What is the price stored as? VARCHAR?

Comment: You appear to be storing prices in the database as text? Why are you doing that?

Comment: IMHO you stored the values wrongly. If they're prices, you should store them as Decimals and add the dot when you display it on the site. We do that too, on our German sites.

Comment: You might be better off storing your prices as plain numbers, then formatting them in your presentation layer. That way, they can be region specific too!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Order by price" returns a weird order in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887760/order-by-price-returns-a-weird-order-in-mysql)

Comment: unfortunately the price has been already stored as longtext and I can't change the type data

Comment: You didn't mention anything about decimals but I added a solution with both: decimales and without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is expecting to get this result:

```
120
10.000
20.000
25.000
25.000
```

Now,

```
select price from t
order by CAST(price  AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

And:

```
select price from t
Order by price+0 ASC
```

Will both return this:

```
10.000
20.000
25.000
25.000
120
```

He will need to parse the field somehow:

```
select price from t
order by replace(price, '.', '')+0;
```

Which gives the expected result.

You can play with it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76b7a/6)

Also note if you have decimals (which are separated by `','`) you might have to use this query:

```
select price from t
order by replace(replace(price, '.', ''), ',', '.')+0;
```

Now, of course the idea is not to store them as text...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Don't store them as strings. You should use a `DECIMAL(10, 2)` instead, where 10 is the total number of digits it can store and 2 is how many of those are on the right hand side of the decimal point. You can adjust the parameters as appropriate, but storing them as strings isn't a very good idea.

Comment: This is not correct. In your example you have 4 digits on the left of the separator and 2 on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Seems price comumn is varchar.

You neeed to `cast` it in int float or double

```
ORDER BY CAST(price  AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

or simple you can use below sort trick on order by clause

```
Order by price+0 ASC
```

Comment: I doubt that would work any better. Surely it would still interpret the period as a decimal point?

Comment: Take into account that `.` is a thousand separator and it will be interpreted as a decimal separator.